# Object Model Schema to Adjust the Schema of other Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, ecmascript-5

### Hi,

**Question:** How can I build a function that:

1. Recive a object by argument;
2. It's a schema model for the second argument;
3. The second argument is a array of objects that has not the same model of the first argument;

**Objective:** The return need be a array of objects with this modifications:

1. Need be removed each of each element the properties that does't exist on the first argument (the object model);
2. For the properties that doesn't exist on element need be created with NULL value;
3. Finally, the other properties of each element need persist with the same value;

**Example** - call function:

```js
    padronizarCom({id: 1, nome:'abcd'}, [{nome:'Carlos', idade:30}, {a:'x', b:'y', c:'z'}])

  // **output:**
  // 0:{nome: "Carlos", id: null}
  // 1:{nome: null, id: null}
```

```js
const padronizarCom = (object,array) => array.reduce(
    (accum, { id, nome}, i) => (
      {
        ...accum,
        [i]: {id, nome}
      }),
    {} 
   );
   
   
   console.log(padronizarCom({id: 1, nome:'abcd'}, [{nome:'felipe', idade:27}, {a:'x', b:'y', c:'z'}]));
```

#### But this solution is too specific to a generic problem. any ideia ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is close to a one-liner with `map()` and `reduce()`. It would be easier if you could return `undefined` instead of `null` for non-existent keys:

```js
function padronizarCom(schema, obj) {
  return obj.map(item => Object.keys(schema)
            .reduce((a, key) => (a[key] = (item[key] !== undefined ? item[key] : null), a), {}))

}

let ret = padronizarCom({id: 1, nome:'abcd'}, [{nome:'Carlos', idade:30}, {a:'x', b:'y', c:'z'}])
console.log(ret)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a better function for this as you are mapping one array to another.

```js
function padronizarCom(schema, array) {
  let keys = Object.keys(schema);
  return array.map(obj => {
    let newObj = {};
    // build new object using keys from schema
    keys.forEach(key => {
      // use existing object's key if it exist; otherwise null
      newObj[key] = obj.hasOwnProperty(key) ? obj[key] : null;
    });
    return newObj;
  });
}

console.log(
  padronizarCom({id: 1, nome:'abcd'}, [{nome:'Carlos', idade:30 }, {a:'x', b:'y', c:'z'}])
)
```

Comment: Small edge case: `{nome:'Carlos', id:0}`  in the input will return `{nome:'Carlos', id:null}`